# How do payment gateway servers close client connection after certain time?

Tags: session, client-server

I do not know if stackoverflow is the right place to ask this question. But I have this doubt in my mind for a long time, so I am asking it here.

I have seen many payment gateways that have certain time limit before the page expires or server closes connection. The user is expected to enter the password and complete verification before the page expires. This is not done using session or javascript. So, how does the server close the client connection, without getting any request from the client?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the client does not make any requests?

This site uses a mixture html, javascript and browser cookies to manage users connections. So if javascript is disabled it falls back into html/cookies for authentication/login/logout and only admits OpenID credentials.

HTML provides methods for sending/recieving information, so you don't have to rely entirely on JavaScript, although JS certainly improves the experience and features.

Sorry if my answer is somehwat vague, as your question was vague as well.